# How is it that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I saw somewhere online for a statistical distribution moment calculation that:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$

for $|t| \leq 1$.

It appears that the right hand side is related to some kind of trigonometric function, but I cannot for the life of me see how this is true. Would anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: You may look into the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the (infinite) Taylor series of the function on the right-hand-side, around $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The Newton binomial series is 
$$
(1+x)^α = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{α}{k}x^k
$$
Now set $x=-t^2$, $α=-\frac12$ and observe that
\begin{align}
\binom{-1/2}{k}
&=\frac{(-\frac12)(-\frac12-1)…(-\frac12-k+1)}{k!}
\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^k\frac{(2k-1)(2k-3)…5·3·1}{k!}
\\
&=\left(-\frac14\right)^k\frac{(2k)!}{k!^2}
\end{align}
The last step is by filling the gaps with even numbers.

If you now compose everything, the given formula results.